# Google plus SDK for iOS gives error file not found?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I'm using [Google plus](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) sdk for login using Google plus in my app. Every thing is working perfectly on my machine(i tested even other machine in my office), but i gave the source code to client. Where project failed to build, giving Google plus files not found.I checked source code on remote machine via TV and it seems every thing ok for me.But code failed to build.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
here is screenshot of framework search path in target build setting[image]

**Edit**: I found that the same code not running in one of my machine which we don't use for iOS developement, just installed xcode 6.1 and tried to build and i got same problem which my client facing.
So is it some xcode setup related problem(also my client is not technical guy he just want to be sure that i given him correct code so i think he is also using xcode very first time in his machine :P).

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted full error message,
I can only predict that "Library Search Paths" is set to your local path.

[image]

So, check if it's set relatively, like in this screenshot (NOT full path like "/Users/Bharat/Documents/XcodeProjects/YourProject/Libraries")

Comment: i didn't set Library search path, only framework search path and Header search path

Comment: I have added the screen shot, please have a look

Comment: hm... GooglePlus SDK added there?, also you need to verify that .framework file is in project directory (it's copied to project)

Comment: yes i checked that and all three files(GooglePlus.framework, GooglePlus.bundle, GoogleOpenSource.framework) are present there.

Comment: hm.. try to copy whole project folder to another directory, and build again.